# Laravel scheduler starts running but is not finishing and not showing any errors

Tags: laravel, command, scheduler

i have a little problem with the laravel scheduler. I've several commands that i run every night and some run only occassionally:

```
 $schedule->command('removeSpacesFromPhoneNumbers:now')->dailyAt('00:30')->withoutOverlapping(10);

 $schedule->command('setContentVisibility:setvisibility')->dailyAt('00:00')->withoutOverlapping(10);

 $schedule->command('sendNewUserNotifications:send')->dailyAt('01:00')->withoutOverlapping(10);

 $schedule->command('removeUnfinishedRegistrations:now')->monthly()->withoutOverlapping(10);

 $schedule->command('setInstitutionID:now')->dailyAt('01:30')->withoutOverlapping(10);

 $schedule->command('createAngeboteIndex:all')->dailyAt('03:00')->withoutOverlapping(10);

 $schedule->command('contentsToApp:now')->dailyAt('02:30')->withoutOverlapping(10);

 $schedule->command('calculateDateTimeTable:now')->weeklyOn(1, '3:30')->withoutOverlapping(10);
```

the scheduler runs just fine and triggers the commands at the set times but the commands do not run till the end. For example i have a command that checks all contents of a certain content type every night to figure out whether a specific content should remain public or not:

```
  public function handle()
{
    Log::info("Set content visibility start");

    $contents = Content::All();

    $nowDate = date("Y-m-d");
    $nowDateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    foreach ($contents as $key => $content) {

        if($content->tname()=='institution'){
            continue;
        }

        if(isset($content->public_to) || isset($content->public_from)){

            if(($content->public_to < $nowDateTime || $content->public_from > $nowDateTime) && $content->view_status==1){
                $content->view_status=0;
                $content->save();
            }

            if($content->public_from <= $nowDateTime && $content->public_to >= $nowDateTime && $content->view_status==0){
                $content->view_status=1;
                $content->save();
            }


            $dateFrom = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($content->public_from));
            $dateTo = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($content->public_to));

            $to = explode("-", $dateTo);
            $from = explode("-", $dateFrom);

            if($to[0]=="1970" && $from[0]=="1970"){

                $now = explode("-",date("Y-m-d"));

                if(($to[1]>=$now[1] && $to[2]>=$now[2]) && ($from[1]<=$now[1] && $from[2]<=$now[2])){
                    $content->view_status=1;
                    $content->save();
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    $content->view_status=0;
                    $content->save();
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        if($content->datespan()!=null){
            if($content->datespan()->end < $nowDate){
               $content->view_status=0;
               $content->save();
           }
       }

       /*Deactivate Contents that have an appointment at a certain date and that are expired*/
       $last = $content->lastAppointment();
       if(isset($last) && $last->date<$nowDate){
        $content->view_status=0;
        $content->save();
    }

    $lf=$content->getProperty('offer_laufender_einstieg');
    if($lf == "" || $lf==false){
        $first = $content->firstAppointment();
        if(isset($first) && $first->date<=$nowDate){
            $content->view_status=0;
            $content->save();
        }
    }
}
Log::info("Set content visibility finished");
```

}

as you can see i added a Log-entry at the beginning and at the end of each run. My Log shows the Entry at beginning but never shows the entry that marks the end of the command. When i run the command without the scheduler everything works just fine.

What do i miss here? Is there an issue with my understanding how the commands need to be scheduled? Help is very much appreciated!

Kind regards

Alex